# How to read the file in opposite direction in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write the script where i am searching a keyword . As soon as i am getting that keyword  i have to backtrack the file i mean i have to start reading the file in opposite direction until i get the desired lines.

**here is my code :**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(my $f1,"<","$file") or die "can not open the file $!\n";
open(my $f2,">","$file_01") or die "can not open the file $!\n";
my @eof =<$f1>;

    for(my $i=0;$i<=$#eof;$i++)
      {
         my $line=$eof[$i];
          if($line=~ m/installd: eof/gi)
         {
            print $line $f2;
            my $j=$i;
            for($j;$j<=0;$j--)
            {
            my $back_line=$eof[$j];
             if($back_line=~ m/Fatal/gi)
              {
                print $back_line $f2;
                exit;
              }
            }
          }
              }
```

Here is the log:

```
06-05 16:37:43.903   274   404 E ThermalEngine: algo_monitor: Timer EVT
06-05 16:37:43.903   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-POPMEM Read pop_mem 53000mC, Err 27000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:43.903   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-CPU3 Read cpu3 54000mC, Err 36000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:43.903   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-CPU2 Read cpu2 54000mC, Err 36000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:43.903   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-CPU1 Read cpu1 57000mC, Err 33000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:43.903   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-CPU0 Read cpu0 63000mC, Err 27000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:43.903   274   404 E ThermalEngine: settimer: Start timer 0.325(sec)
06-05 16:37:43.903   274   404 E ThermalEngine: algo_monitor: Wait for EV
06-05 16:37:43.943 16232 16232 D StatusBar.NetworkController: onDataActivity: direction=0
06-05 16:37:43.943 16232 16232 D StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ data } level=4 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020138/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_4 combinedActivityIconId=0x0 mobileLabel=AIRCEL wifiLabel= emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel=AIRCEL mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020138 mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02005f mDataDirectionIconId=0x7f020113 mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020138 mDataTypeIconId=0x7f020113 mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f020061 mNoSimIconId=0x0 mWifiIconId=0x0 mQSWifiIconId=0x0 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080563
06-05 16:37:43.943 16232 16232 D StatusBar.NetworkController: changing data overlay icon id to 0
06-05 16:37:43.953 16090 16091 F libc    : **Fatal signal** 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5f106dc8 (code=1), thread 16091 (SurfaceFlinger)
06-05 16:37:44.243   274   404 E ThermalEngine: algo_monitor: Timer EVT
06-05 16:37:44.243   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-POPMEM Read pop_mem 53000mC, Err 27000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:44.243   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-CPU3 Read cpu3 54000mC, Err 36000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:44.243   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-CPU2 Read cpu2 54000mC, Err 36000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:44.243   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-CPU1 Read cpu1 57000mC, Err 33000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:44.243   274   404 E ThermalEngine: handle_timer_sig: SS Id SS-CPU0 Read cpu0 63000mC, Err 27000mC, SampleCnt 5
06-05 16:37:44.243   274   404 E ThermalEngine: settimer: Start timer 0.325(sec)
06-05 16:37:44.243   274   404 E ThermalEngine: algo_monitor: Wait for EV
06-05 16:37:44.263   262   262 I DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'audio' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'network_management' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'textservices' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'netstats' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'netpolicy' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'wifip2p' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'uimode' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'dropbox' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'cneservice' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'country_detector' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'connectivity' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'servicediscovery' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'throttle' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'updatelock' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'commontime_management' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'devicestoragemonitor' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'notification' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'search' died
06-05 16:37:49.193   256   256 I ServiceManager: service 'location' died
06-05 16:37:49.213  8379  8379 W AudioFlinger: power manager service died !!!
06-05 16:37:49.213  8379  8379 W AudioFlinger: power manager service died !!!
06-05 16:37:49.213   300  1913 I Atfwd_Sendcmd: AtCmdFwd : binderDied
06-05 16:37:49.223   300  1913 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
06-05 16:37:49.233   268   268 E **installd: eof**
06-05 16:37:49.233   268   268 E installd: failed to read size
06-05 16:37:49.233   268   268 I installd: closing connection
06-05 16:37:49.233   268   268 I installd: new connection
06-05 16:37:49.243 30568 30588 I SystemServer: Entropy Mixer
06-05 16:37:49.283 30568 30588 I QCOM PowerHAL: QCOM power HAL initing.
06-05 16:37:49.283 30568 30588 I SystemServer: Power Manager
```

in the above log i am searching for :EOF first once i am getting that keyword then i have to read the file in opposite direction until i get the FATAL (first encounter only) . I am printing both information in some other file.

For me it seems logic is correct but while running this program i am getting error. do we have another way to perform this task ?

Comment: There is no situation ever when posting a question here on Stackoverflow that you should not include all of the error messages exactly as they appear. They are probably the most important piece of information you can give, and you left them out.

Comment: So what you want is essentially getting the last line containing pattern A that comes before the line containing pattern B, and extracting both lines to another file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you would never read a file backwards. At least not in any scenario that is as simple as this. You just store the last read `Fatal` match and print it when `eof` is found:

```
my $fatal;
while (<>) {
    if (/Fatal/) {
        $fatal = $_;          # store line for later
    }
    if (/installd: eof/) {
        print $fatal;         # stored line
        print $_;             # current line
    }
}
```

Note that I removed the `/gi` options on your regexges because they are redundant here. You do not want a case insensitive match, and you do not need to match multiple times.

Comment: @ TLP  i have modified my code with the one you have suggested me above but i am getting one error "Can't use string ("06-05 16:37:43.953 16090 16091 F"...) as a symbol ref while
strict refs" in use at Modified_apstrss_log_analysis.pl line 55, <FH> line 809"

Comment: foreach $file (@File_01)
  {
   if($file =~ /APStress.*UIlog/g)
    {
      open(FH,"<","$dir_01/$dir_02/$file") or die "can not open the file $!\n";
   open(my $fh,">", "$dir_01/$dir_02/$new_file") or die "Can not write in he file\n";
   while (defined(my $line = <FH>))
     { 
    if ($line=~/Fatal/) 
     {
                $fatal = $line;          # store line for later
            }
    if($line=~ m/installd: eof/)
          {
             print $fatal $fh;         # stored line
                   print $line  $fh;         # current line
   } 
  }
     }
   }
 }

Comment: @Maverick Well, the syntax is `print FILEHANDLE LIST`, not the other way around.

Comment: @ TLP ..ohh in a hurray i just missed the syntax .anyways thanks .. its working now :)

Comment: @Maverick You may wish to add some safety precautions, such as resetting `$fatal` after its printed (to avoid missing data being duplicated), and preventing undefined values in `$fatal` being printed.

Comment: It seems that current line should go before stored one.

Comment: @mpapec I thought it would be more logical to keep them in the order they appear, but that's up to the OP of course.

Answer (score 1):

It will always save last fatal line, and print it together with current line which matches eof,

```
perl -ne '$fatal=$_ if /Fatal/i; print $_,$fatal if /installd: eof/i' file > file_01
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the needless complexity, there are three problems that stop your program running correctly and cleanly

- You don't declare and define `$file` and `$file_01`
- `print $line $f2` should be `print $f2 $line`
- `for ($j; $j <= 0; $j--) { ... }` should be `for (; $j >= 0; $j--)` (the comparison is reversed, and mentioning `$j` on its own is superfluous and would probably generate a warning

This version of your code runs satisfactorily, but is very much the wrong solution!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV = qw/ logfile.txt outfile.txt /;

my ($file, $file_01) = @ARGV;

open(my $f1, '<', $file)    or die "can not open the file: $!";
open(my $f2, '>', $file_01) or die "can not open the file: $!";

my @eof = <$f1>;

for my $i (0 .. $#eof) {
  my $line = $eof[$i];
  if ($line =~ m/installd: eof/) {
    print $f2 $line;
    my $j = $i;
    while (--$j >= 0) {
      my $back_line = $eof[$j];
      if ($back_line =~ m/Fatal/) {
        print $f2 $back_line;
        exit;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the log file is large it will be faster to use the 'tac' command in Linux if the patterns appear near the bottom. Opposite of cat. It lists the lines in opposite order. This will also find the last /eof/ pattern if there are more than one of them:

```
tac file.log|perl -ne'$eof=$_ if /eof/; print $eof,$_ and exit if $eof and /fatal/'
```